# How do I design this magnetic bed?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnets

I am looking to design a bed of magnets that I can lay on for health improvement. Ignoring any health concerns, the objective is to create the "purest" AND strongest negative field (NORTH POLE) for me to lay on.

I have no experience in this so please practice patience with me. The reason I emphasize "purest" is because when you place two magnets side by side to each other I am not sure how they influence each other. I am not sure if the positive pole (South Pole) bleeds into the negative pole (North pole). The MAIN QUESTIONS I have are the following...

Q1: What does the distance between the magnets need to be to provide the "purest" AND strongest negative (north pole) field? For example if I place two 6" x 4" x 1" side by side at 3/4" apart versus spacing them 1" apart does that have influence on the fields, their strength or how the North and South Poles interact?

Q2: After creating the "purest" and strongest field at what distance above the magnets will the "purest" negative field exist? For example if I was at a distance of 1/4" ABOVE the north side is it totally a negative field or is there some influence from the positive field? If so at what distance above the magnets will there be a 90-100% negative field?

**Please see below for my current design and other important notes. I have also linked a Google Drive Link below that contains a PDF of the project. Thanks for any help!

Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_aC2vsoOjvhp1Lv0SODDAfUSEpC65NiH/view?usp=sharing

OBJECTIVES:

Create "purest" AND strongest negative field for me to lay on. Meaning no Positive (South Pole) can be present in the area I am laying.

MATERIALS:

(140) 6" x 4" x 1" Ceramic Magnet (C8)

DESIGN CONCEPT:[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ummmm, magnets don't have positive and negative fields or poles. I'm not worried about health concerns. I don't think there are any health effects at all.

Comment: you're already living in a magnetic field

Comment: how will you prevent yourself from turning over in your bed? ... because, if you turn over, then the field will reverse direction through your body ... you'll always have north on one side of your body and south on the other side ... 
  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=magnetic+field+lines&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 1):

I don't wish to encourage you in this project as I think you have picked up some bogus terminology (positive and negative fields and poles) from whatever sources you have been reading and I suspect that any health claims are bogus too. However, we can explain some of the resultant field from a grid of magnets.

[image]

*Figure 1. Magnetic field of adjacent magnets. Image created by me.*

The lines of magnetic flux will radiate from the north pole to the south pole with the greatest concentration at the shortest path. In your case, with flat magnets this will be at the edges of the magnets so introducing *any* gap will result in much of the field being lost.

The second problem is that, as should be obvious from the diagram, the lines of flux towards the centre of the north pole initially radiate upwards but then turn south. Any "body" in that field will experience an upward field over the centre of the magnet, a horizontal field over the edge and a downward field over the gap.

I recommend two areas to study:

1. Physics of magnets and magnetic fields.
2. Properly reviewed scientific studies of the health benefits of magnets. (Good luck!)